# httplib modifying my regex xml POST message

Tags: python, python-2.7, httplib

I try to make a soapclient in Python.

I get an answer, but my Problem is that httplib ist converting my POST:

From

> (.*)\|WebSphere\|wast/test(.*)

in

> (.*)\\|WebSphere\\|wast/test(.*)

What can I do for preventing the code modifying any special characters that I could have in the regex string ?

Comment: How exactly are you displaying and setting the characters? Some inputs of \\ will map to \ and outputs vice versa

Comment: I'm only making :
webservice = httplib.HTTP(host)
webservice.putrequest("POST", url)
    ...
webservice.send(message)

It doesn't matter if I have \\ or \, in the output there is always two...

Comment: In Fact I've checked, a print is doing well, only httplib makes problems